# Direct ByteBuffer and thread safety

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm learning about OpenGL ES, and I see a lot of examples that allocate a direct `ByteBuffer`, then wrap it in a `FloatBuffer` and write vertex data to it in [Renderer#onDrawFrame(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onDrawFrame%28javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10%29).

Why is this thread-safe?  (Or is it?)  Is it a characteristic of a direct `ByteBuffer`, or something done by the caller of `onDrawFrame(...)`, that ensures that writes to the buffer are visible to the shader programs?

**Edit**: My understanding of the JMM is that it is what it is because Java exposes some of the complexity of modern hardware.  I'm assuming that the same memory visibility issues that exist between Java threads also exist between a Java thread and a non-Java program accessing the same memory.  I'm further assuming that shaders run on the GPU, not in the Java rendering thread.

If all of the above is correct, then there must be a memory barrier somewhere to ensure that writes in the rendering thread are visible to the shader.  My question boils down to, **where is that memory barrier?**  Is it my responsibility to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, all of the allocating and populating happens on the renderer thread, so there's no thread-safety issue.  There is nothing special about direct ByteBuffers in this regard.  If an app is writing from one thread and reading from another with no synchronization, then it's possible a race condition exists.

If the GLES driver decides to use multiple threads, it's responsible for issuing appropriate memory barriers.

cf. [Android SMP Primer](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html)

**Edit** (to match edit in question): the app's responsibility is to access the EGL context from one thread at a time (which I'm calling the "renderer thread").  If you submit data to GLES from a buffer with data races, you're going to have a bad time.  So long as the renderer thread has a consistent view, everything you do with GLES on that thread will work as expected.

If the GLES implementation happens to execute shaders on a different CPU thread or in the GPU, it's the GLES driver's responsibility to handle memory consistency issues.

Comment: My question is about write visibility between the rendering thread and the shader, not between the rendering thread and other Java threads.  Edited to clarify.